# How do i multiply an integer with a function in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, towers-of-hanoi

Hey guys i am trying to create a function that Takes one parameter:n and then returns the value of the number of moves required to transfer n disks from peg1 to peg 3 in Tower of Hanoi problem.
Hints: Total number of moves for n disks,
H(n)    = 2H(n-1)+1, if n>1
= 1, if n = 1.
I have implemented the code in python and it works fine but when i implement it in scheme i come up with a wrong answer. I am very new to scheme and would be thankful if you guys help me to see where i messed up. The code i've come up with is given below:

```
(define(hanoi n)
      (if(< n 2)
          1
      (+(* 2 (hanoi(- n 1) 1)))))
(display(hanoi 4))
```

Comment: What actually happened when you ran this function? If there was an error message: what was it?  Now look at the code (hint, indenting it, or letting the editor do that for you may help).

Comment: Hi, it was giving me a wrong answer i.e. it was returning 8 when i write (display(hanoi 4)) . But the correct answer is 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing two parameters to `hanoi`, but it expects only one, the parentheses are misplaced. This is how the recurrence relation formula looks like in Scheme - and please, take note of how you should indent and format your code! even better, let your editor do it properly for you:

```
(define (hanoi n)
  (if (< n 2)
      1
      (+ (* 2 (hanoi (- n 1))) 1)))


(hanoi 4)
=> 15
```

BTW: there's a closed-form solution for this problem, you don't need to write a recursive procedure to find the number of moves - just apply the formula `2**n - 1`:

```
(define (hanoi n)
  (- (expt 2 n) 1))

(hanoi 4)
=> 15
```

Comment: Thank you! I am actually using an online interpreter which doesn't auto indent the code but i will keep your advice in mind.